# how to update database from nestedsortable to hierachical

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, nested-sortable

I want to know how to update my database based on this type of array:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 58
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 62
                            [children] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => Array
                                        (
                                            [id] => 61
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 60
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 63
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [children] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 59
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

I tried different methods but it's not working as it should.

Here's my function that saved the new order of my list, I use `nestedSortable('toHierarchy')`

```
function order()
{
    $list = $_POST['list'];
    foreach ($list as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value['children'])) {
            $i=1;
            foreach($value['children'] as $k=>$v) {
                $this->section->edit(array('order' => $i, 'parent_id'=>$value['id']), 
                                     "WHERE `id`=" . $v['id']);
                echo 'parent '.$value['id'].'child->'.$v['id'].' order->'.$i.'<br/>';
                $i++;
            }
        }
        else {
            $this->section->edit(array('order' => $key, 'parent_id'=>0), 
                                 "WHERE `id`=" . $value['id']);
        }
    }
}
```

But it's not working for list with more than 2 levels.

this is the js i'm using

```
$('ol.sortable').nestedSortable({
         update : function () {
var orderNew = $(this).nestedSortable('serialize', {startDepthCount: 0});
//alert(orderNew);
        $.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            url: '<?php echo (APP_URL); ?>projects/<?php echo $project_id; ?>/sections/order_list',
            data: {list:orderNew}
            });             
},
            disableNesting: 'no-nest',
            forcePlaceholderSize: true,
            handle: 'div',
            helper: 'clone',
            items: 'li',
            maxLevels: 4,
            opacity: .6,
            placeholder: 'placeholder',
            revert: 250,
            tabSize: 25,
            tolerance: 'move',
            toleranceElement: '> div'
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could implement a recursive function to deal with unlimited nesting levels. But I suggest as an alternative to use the nested sortable `serialize` method:

```
$('your_sortable_selector').nestedSortable('serialize');
```

This generates a flat array with the keys being the **item id** and the values for each key being the **parent id**. You can then implement a less complicated function like so:

```
function order()
{
    $list = $_POST['list'];

    // an array to keep the sort order for each level based on the parent id as the key
    $sort = array();
    foreach ($list as $id => $parentId) {
        /* a null value is set for parent id by nested sortable for root level elements
           so you set it to 0 to work in your case (from what I could deduct from your code) */
        $parentId = ($parentId === null) ? 0 : $parentId;

        // init the sort order value to 1 if this element is on a new level
        if (!array_key_exists($parentId, $sort)) {
            $sort[$parentId] = 1;
        }

        $this->section->edit(array('order' => $sort[$parentId], 'parent_id' => $parentId), "WHERE `id`= $id");

        // increment the sort order for this level
        $sort[$parentId]++;
    }
}
```

This should work just as well for any number of nesting levels.

Comment: thank you but there's a problem it seems that i get this error : Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: Are you posting the list correctly? What's the value of `$_POST['list']` you get when the function is called? (`Invalid argument supplied for foreach()` means that the `$list` variable doesn't contain an array. Post the javascript code that serializes the nested sortable. Are you using ajax or storing the serialized list as a form input value?

Comment: list[58][pos]=root&list[58][title]=undefined&list[58][class]=undefined&list[58][type]=undefined&list[58][content]=undefined&list[62][pos]=58&list[62][title]=undefined&list[62][class]=undefined&list[62][type]=undefined&list

Comment: Remove the `startDepthCount` since I don't think that's needed: `var orderNew = $(this).nestedSortable('serialize');`. Also do a `console.log(orderNew)` on the next line and post here the string from your browser console (I'm assuming you're using Chrome or Firefox).

Comment: Also just to make sure. You're using this plugin http://mjsarfatti.com/sandbox/nestedSortable/ ... right?

Comment: Also change the ajax `data` parameter to this: `data: orderNew` instead of `data: {list:orderNew}`

Comment: list[58][class] undefined
list[58][content] undefined
list[58][pos] root
list[58][title] undefined
list[58][type] undefined
list[59][class] undefined
list[59][content] undefined
list[59][pos] 62
list[59][title]

Comment: According to the docs here https://github.com/mjsarfatti/nestedSortable#custom-methods you should be getting a query string like so `list[id]=parentId&list[id]=parentId`. Is your list html markup correct? Meaning is it each `li` should have the an id like so `<li id="list_id">` where `id` is the id used in your database

Comment: yes the format it's correct i've pasted the post data prev on comments

Comment: Then it's strange. Are you using the latest version of the plugin? Also could you please post the html markup of the sortable lists, maybe I can spot something there

Comment: thank you so much that was the problem i was using 1.3.4 version many thanks